# Many to many Laravel 5.1, not working, parameter mismatch (string, array)

Tags: php, many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-5.1

I was following this tutorials https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/21 but can't make my many to many migrations to work. Without further ado here's the code:

Migrations:

create Locations

```
    Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name');
    });
```

create Locationtypes

```
    Schema::create('locationtypes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name');
    });
```

create pivot table location_locationtype

```
    Schema::create('location_locationtype', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('location_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('locationtype_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Models:

Locationtype

```
class Locationtype extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'locationtypes';
  protected $fillable = ['name'];
  public function locations()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Location')->withTimestamps();
  }
}
```

Location

```
class Location extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'locations';
  protected $fillable = ['name'];
  public function locationtypes()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Locationtype')->withTimestamps();
  }
}
```

LocationController@store

```
public function store(Requests\LocationRequest $request)
{
    $location = Location::create($request->all());
    $location->locationtypes()->attach($request->input('locationtype'));
}
```

Outputs: `preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array`. I have no idea which string is it trying to replace with an array (which I suppose is $request->input('locationtype').

If I dd as:

```
public function store(Requests\LocationRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->input('locationtype'));
}
```

I get:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "1"
  1 => "3"
]
```

which is good, since I selected first and third `Locationtype`. If I don't select any of the locationtype, array will be empty, and there will be no error.

Also if I change the function to:

```
public function store(Requests\LocationRequest $request)
{
    Location::create($request->all());
}
```

I still get the same error as long as I have element below in my form.

Form elment:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('locationtype', 'Type of location') !!}
    {!! Form::select('locationtype[]', $locationtypes, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple']) !!}
</div>
```

`$locationtypes` gives right values.

Thank you all, and request if more information is needed.

### EDIT:

If I change the function to

```
    $location = new Location;
    $location->locationtypes()->attach($request->input('locationtype'));
```

pivot table gets filled. So the problem is in creating new `Location` with `$request->all();`.

Comment: it said, your input from locationtype is a string, and u are trying to use attach function by just sending a string.

Comment: @MaXi32 Let me try to rephrase you to be sure I got you right. You are saying that at this line `$location->locationtypes()->attach($request->input('locationtype'));` `locationtype` is a string?
But if I do `dd($request->input('locationtype'));` I get an array.

Comment: I think it would be adult way to leave a comment if and why downvoteing.

Comment: did your application worked? i faced the same issue on creating and updating.

Comment: I don't really remember what exactly was the problem. Did you tried what I said below? Also maybe using `sync` instead of `attach` would make a difference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Thing is that I always dumbdown this SO questions so I don't have the same thing in my app where I could look. However, I don't encounter any problems with m2m relations anymore so there's a solution, and probably a simple one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
Location::create($request->all());
```

with

```
$location = Location::create($request->except('locationtype'));
```

I worked it out after some deduction and trial and error. Would appreciate if someone would comment and explain what went wrong and why did I need to except the `locationtype`.

HF all, and good coding.